# How to fetch Last Row Record from Sql Server Database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I Want to fetch 3 Unique Last Row Record from Database in Sql Server. Plz Suggest Query.

Ex: Table Name : ABC

```
(Column 1)       (Column 2)
First_Name       Last_Name

Ram              Sharma
Shyam            Gupta
Ranu             Gahlot
Kanchan          Verma
Monu             Vyas
Sohan            Jain
Monu             Vyas
Sohan            Jain
Monu             Vyas
Sohan            Jain
Shyam            Gupta
Ranu             Gahlot
Ranu             Gahlot
Ranu             Gahlot
Shyam            Gupta
Shyam            Gupta
```

Now I am using this query (Select distinct top 3 First_Name, Last_Name from ABC) then find that result. :

```
Shyam            Gupta
Ranu             Gahlot
Kanchan          Verma
```

But actually, I want to get this result. So Suggest me....

Result :

```
Shyam   Gupta
Ranu    Gahlot
Sohan   Jain
```

Note: By last I mean chronologically not alphabetically. And i do not have id column.

Comment: Do you have an ID column? How do you define "last" rows? Last alphabetically?

Comment: Can you describe in English what the meaning of the desired result?

Comment: You need an ORDER BY to define last. What is the column that you order by to get this?

Comment: Chronologically not alphabetically and i do not have id column.

Comment: If you want **chronologically** - do you have some kind of a `DATETIME` column?

Comment: It is better to keep an auto id column

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM [YOURTABLE] ORDER BY FirstName DESC Limit 3
```

Answer (score 0):

select top 1 *  from [TABLE_NAME]  order by [COl_NAME] desc